# nested iFrame facebook app with facebooker on IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebooker

I've tried to create simple facebook app with iFrame,, but I always get nested iFrame on every I click link on my application, I already tried a solution from site http://railsrant.com/2009/10/14/creating-a-facebook-iframe-app-using-ruby-on-rails-facebooker/
it's work on Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't work at IE

Any idea or suggestion for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add `target="_top"` to your `<a href="...">` links

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this line in your head section, this will open the links in parent window instead of iframe in iframe:

```
 <base target="_parent" />
```

and also make these URL related to canvasURL(facebook app URL). I hope this will solve your problem.